# Building pyhunspell on Windows

Tags: python, mingw, mingw-w64, hunspell

I'm on Windows with 64bit Python 2.7

I downloaded [hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) and [pyhunspell](https://code.google.com/p/pyhunspell/).

Using 64bit MinGW system I successfully compiled hunspell project - resulting in working executable hunspell tools and hunspell library. After the build this is my folder structure:

```
+---hunspell-0.1
\---hunspell-1.3.3
    +---intl
    +---m4
    +---man
    |   \---hu
    +---po
    +---src
    |   +---hunspell
    |   |   +---.deps
    |   |   \---.libs
    |   +---parsers
    |   |   +---.deps
    |   |   \---.libs
    |   +---tools
    |   |   +---.deps
    |   |   \---.libs
    |   \---win_api
    \---tests
        \---suggestiontest
```

In folder `hunspell-0.1` I have pyhunspell project. I opened `setup.py` file and changed it like this:

```
main = Extension('hunspell',
                 libraries = ['../hunspell-1.3.3/src/hunspell/.libs/hunspell-1.3'],
                 include_dirs = ['../hunspell-1.3.3/src/hunspell'],
                 sources = ['hunspell.c'],
                 extra_compile_args = ['-Wall'])
```

Executing `python setup.py build -c mingw32` results in this: [build log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/63903e92d216f09d394e/raw/a33f51a50a86356973109dad85dae05c41a0915f/build.log) ending with error message:

`c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-mingw_helpers.o): bad reloc address 0x0 in section ".pdata"'`

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I made Python package in a strange way:

1. Changed already changed `setup.py` with this line:

   `libraries = ['../hunspell-1.3.3/src/hunspell/.libs/libhunspell-1.3']`
2. Renamed

   `hunspell-1.3.3/src/hunspell/.libs/libhunspell-1.3.dll.a`

   to

   `hunspell-1.3.3/src/hunspell/.libs/libhunspell-1.3.lib`
3. Compile with default compiler - MSVC:

   `python setup.py build`

   `python setup.py install`
4. Copy

   `hunspell-1.3.3/src/hunspell/.libs/libhunspell-1.3-0.dll`

   to site-packages.

Import.